# multiple values per key in java

Tags: java

I want to add multiple values to a map key. I tried many ways, but every time I get an error at some points.

Here is what I tried

```
List<Employee>listWmp = new ArrayList<>();
        listWmp.add(0, emp1);
        listWmp.add(1, emp2);
        listWmp.add(2, emp3);
        listWmp.add(3, emp4);
        listWmp.add(4, emp5);
        System.out.println("list elements are : "+listWmp);
        //convert the list into map
       Map<String, Employee> listMap = listWmp.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, employee -> employee));
       System.out.println("list to map values :"+listMap);
Map<String, List<Employee>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<Employee>();
```

I want the below result. How do I add multiple values to a key?

```
empId=1, empBame=Mayank, empDepartment=HR, emil=mayank@gmail.com
empId=1,empBame=Mahesh, empDepartment=Trainer, emil=Mahesh@gmail.com
```

Comment: Duplicate keys are not allowed in a Map

Comment: The purpose of a map is to map one key to one value. If a key can have more than one value, then map a key to an object that can contain more than one value, like a `List` or `Set`.

Comment: [*Multimap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) is the technical term. Already covered on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Map<String, List<Employee>> hm = listWmp.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getEmpId));
```

Comment: Some explanation would help.